# cakephp : Save data to another model

Tags: forms, cakephp

ok i got 2 table = `shop` & `tag`

currently in my shops view file 
i got a form.

something like
`echo $this->Form->input('tag_id');`
`echo $this->Form->input('tag1');`
`echo $this->Form->input('tag2');`

well, now in my shops controller...
`if($this->request->is['Post'] {`
`$this->Tag->id = $this->data['Shop']['tag_id'];`
`$this->Tag->save($this->request->data);`

do u get my means ? actually i want get  the form value which input by shops view file , but save to the tag table...
but the shops controller code doesn't works ... i guess so with the `$this->Tag->id = $this->data['Shop']['tag_id'];` part was wrong . any helps pls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference to the model correctly: `$this->Shop->Tag->id=...; $this->Shop->Tag->save(...)` I'm surprised you didn't get an error message when referencing the Tag model like that.

Comment: there got an error shown id is not related model something. just i trying to find out the way how to save the data as following the tag_id i want . i will try with your code.

Comment: between i done assign the Tag->id with your solution $this->Shop->Tag->id ... but i cannot save the data belong to $this->Shop->Tag->id

Answer (score 0):

you could actually try with this to manage.

```
if($this->request->is['Post'] {
     $this->Tag->id = $this->data['Shop']['tag_id'];
     $save_arr['Tag']['tag1'] = $this->data['Shop']['tag1'];
     $save_arr['Tag']['tag2'] = $this->data['Shop']['tag2'];
     $this->Tag->save($save_arr);
}
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: well, @liyakat if there was 20 data need to save ? did i need manually save_arr for both 20 data ? any shortcut to direct save all?

Comment: yes there is way but you must have to good array function command so you can extract data from post array and just need to make array like above as i made.